# Generate list of items with 0 prefix using padStart

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I implemented the way to generate a list of items with iterable counts with prefix 0. What is the best way to generate such kind of list?

Current behaviour:

```
const generateList = (length, n, i) => {
let b = n+i

return b.toString().padStart(length.toString().length + n.toString.length, 0)
}

Array(10).fill(null).map((x, i) => generateList(10,2, i))
```

Output result:

```
["002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "007", "008", "009", "010", "011"]
```

Do u have any idea to make it another way?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: You can use Math.floor((length+n)/)+2 , 0 inside padStart

Comment: I don't think you meant `n.toString.length` which is `1` for any number `n`.

Comment: Is the current output the expected output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-pad-a-value-with-leading-zeros https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073699/pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript

Comment: also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30452263/1048572 (and others linked from there)

Comment: @Bergi actually n can be even 20, any number

Comment: @Bergi yes expected, but I looking for another solution, simplify it. `length` and `n` can be any value

Comment: @PalaniichukDmytro Yes, but even `(20).toString.length` is `1`. What did you intend this to do?

Comment: @Bergi check it in console
`(20).toString().length` // 2
`('20').toString().length` // 2

Comment: @PalaniichukDmytro Yes, but that's  `toString().length` not `toString.length`. Can you explain what you were trying to do with `length.toString().length + n.toString.length`? Did you maybe mean `(length + n).toString().length`?

Answer (score 2):

You could determine the number of characters needed at the start and used the predetermined value to format the output for the array.

```js
function createList(startValue, endValue) {
  let 
    // The minimum output length, for a single digit number, is 2 chars.
    outputLength = 2,
    testValue = 10,
    // Create an empty array which has as many items as numbers we need to
    // generate for the output. Add 1 to the end value as this is to be 
    // inclusive of the range to create. If the +1 is not done the resulting 
    // array is 1 item too small.
    emptyArray = Array(endValue - startValue + 1);
    
  // As long as test value is less than the end value, keep increasing the 
  // output size by 1 and continue to the next multiple of 10.
  while (testValue <= endValue) {
    outputLength++;
    testValue = testValue * 10;
  }
  
  // Create a new array, with the same length as the empty array created
  // earlier. For each position place a padded number into the output array.
  return Array.from(emptyArray, (currentValue, index) => {
    // Pad the current value to the determined max length.
    return (startValue + index).toString().padStart(outputLength, '0');
  });
}

function createListWithLength(length, startValue = 0) {
  return createList(startValue, startValue + length);
}

console.log(createList(2,10));
console.log(createListWithLength(30));
console.log(createListWithLength(10, 995));
```

Comment: the parens are redundant here -> `(endValue + 1) - startValue`

Comment: and use `Array.from(Array(length), fillerFn)` instead filling with `null`s and then mapping over.

Comment: Yeah, I have a things with adding parenthesis where not absolutely necessary. I guess I find it easier to read. I'd actually prefer a good old `for`-loop, have the feeling it would give better performance.

Comment: Didn't know about that second param for the `Array.from` method, thanks!

Comment: I prefer `for..of` cause it can work with iterables (i.e. node lists)

Comment: `Array.from(emptyArray)` doesn't really make much sense. I recommend to use `Array.from({length})`, as only the length is important here

Comment: This `while` loop is essentially just computing the `Math.log10(endValue)`?

Comment: Yeah, that's what the `while` does. Didn't know there is a Math method that basically does the same thing. I used `emptyArray` instead of `Array(end-start+1)` is I felt it increased the readability.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at generators:

```
function* range(from, to) {
  for (var i=from; i<to; i++)
    yield i;
}
function* paddedRange(from, to) {
  const length = (to-1).toString(10) + 1 /* at least one pad */;
  for (const i of range(from, to))
    yield i.padStart(length, '0');
}

console.log(Array.from(paddedRange(2, 12)));
```

You can also inline the loop from `range` into `paddedRange`, or you can make it return an array directly:

```
function paddedRange(from, to) {
  const length = (to-1).toString(10) + 1 /* at least one pad */;
  return Array.from(range(from, to), i => i.padStart(length, '0'));
}

console.log(paddedRange(2, 12));
```

The main simplification is that you should compute the padding length only once and give it a denotative name, instead of computing it for every number again. Also ranges are usually given by their lower and upper end instead of their begin and a length, but you can easily switch back if you need the latter for some reason.

Comment: generators, nice. But I see also good old `var` still used ;)

Comment: @marzelin There's no advantage in using `let` here, as we don't need a block scope.

Comment: so you prefer `var` over `let`, and use `let` only when needed?

Comment: @marzelin I tend use `var` for all function-scoped variables, and `let` when I need a block scope for a closure or don't want to use the variable after the loop. If it doesn't matter (like here) I'll flip a coin or check which side of the bed I got up today :-)

Comment: oh sorry, I meant consistent ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe something like this

```js
const generateList = length => Array(length).fill('0').map((item, index) => item + index);

console.log(generateList(20));
```