# How do I call a function n number of times with functional programming?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

I'm new to functional programming and typescript. I was told to only use recursion so for loops aren't allowed. How do I call a function n number of times with recursion?

Here's the imperative pseudo code

```
for i <- 0 to n:
    f(x) //function call
```

I tried this:

```
function loop(n:number, f:()=>number):number [
    return n > 0? loop(n-1, f) : f;
}
```

but I realised that this only returns f when n = 1. What I want is to call f n number of times. May I know how could this be done?

Comment: `I realised that this only returns f when n = 1` So what happens when `n > 1`?

Comment: What are you supposed to do with the results of the function calls? Just discarding them, like the imperative code does, is meaningless in functional programming. And where should the argument (`x` in your imperative code) come from?

Comment: @Bergi the results are discarded but right now the function is only called once instead of 4 times

Comment: @KennethK. right now it's calling itself for recursion but how can I call itself recursively and call another function at the same time?

Comment: @llamaro25 In the code you have written, you've typed `f` as a `number`, but it should be a function.

Comment: @llamaro25 In your `loop`, `f()` is called *never*? Maybe also show us how you are invoking `loop`.

Comment: @Richiban sorry, I'm still new to typescript. I have edited it, is it correct now?

Comment: If the results of a function call can be discarded, the whole function call can be discarded, and calling the function not once has the same result - none - as calling it a thousand times. So knowing what should happen with the results is essential in functional programming. Please tell us what results you need, or what problem you are trying to solve, and show us an example for the function `f` that you want to pass.

Comment: @llamaro25 No, it's not correct now. It doesn't typecheck. Doesn't your TypeScript compiler show you that?

Comment: If you're just calling a function for its side-effects you might as well just use a for loop since it's inherently imperative. If you really want to use recursion you could do something like `function loop(n, f) { if (n > 0) { f(); loop(n-1, f) } }`.

Comment: You can either do this lazily with a generator `iterate = f => function* (x) {while (true)    yield x = f(x)}` or you must accumulate the results with an `Array`. The latter requires that you determine the length of the `Array` and hence the number of iterations upfront.

Comment: Don't be too dogmatic about forbidding for or while loops. In the end, looping has to be implemented somehow and you could even hide away the while or for loop behind a functional interface.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I replace while loops with a functional programming alternative without tail call optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592016/how-do-i-replace-while-loops-with-a-functional-programming-alternative-without-t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**generics**

I'd probably write it using [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), such as `T` below -

```
function hello (name: string): string {
  return `hello ${name}`;
}

function loop<T>(n: number, f: (x: T) => T, x: T): T {
  return n > 0 ? loop(n-1, f, f(x)) : x;
}

console.log(loop(3, hello, "world"));
// hello hello hello world
```

Which compiles to -

```js
"use strict";
function hello(name) {
    return `hello ${name}`;
}
function loop(n, f, x) {
    return n > 0 ? loop(n - 1, f, f(x)) : x;
}
console.log(loop(3, hello, "world"));
// hello hello hello world
```

---

**don't blow the stack**

Direct recursion can cause a stack-overflow in JavaScript. If you want to loop a function thousands of times, you will need to convert it to a `while` loop [one way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30452949/633183) or [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57739457/633183) -

Here's a simple way -

```
function hello (name: string): string {
  return `hello ${name}`
}

function loop<T>(n: number, f: (x: T) => T, x: T): T {
  while (n-- > 0) x = f(x)
  return x
}

console.log(loop(20000, hello, "world"));
// hello hello hello ... hello world
```

Which compiles to -

```js
"use strict";
function hello(name) {
    return `hello ${name}`;
}
function loop(n, f, x) {
    while (n-- > 0)
        x = f(x);
    return x;
}
console.log(loop(20000, hello, "world"));
// hello hello hello ... hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution with recursion:

```
// Your function
functionName = () => {
  console.log('functionName was called');
}

// Caller function
callFunctionNTimes = n => {
    if(n && n > 0) {
      functionName();
    return callFunctionNTimes(n - 1);
  }
}

// Use
callFunctionNTimes(2);
```

Output:

> functionName was called
>   functionName was called

Simplified syntax:

```
callFunctionNTimes = n => {
    const recursionCondition = n && n > 0;
    recursionCondition && functionName()
    recursionCondition && callFunctionNTimes(n - 1);
}
```

High order function:

```
functionName = () => {
  console.log('functionName was called');
}

callFunctionNTimes = (functionForExecute) => n => {
    const recursionCondition = n && n > 0;
    recursionCondition && functionForExecute();
    recursionCondition && callFunctionNTimes(functionForExecute)(n - 1);
}

callFunctionNTimes(functionName)(2);
```

Comment: `&&` is not "simplified syntax", it's *minified* syntax at best. It's confusing and abuse of the operator.

Comment: Minimalism is a JavaScript paradigm, isn't it?

Comment: In the sense that JavaScript is a multi-paradigm language, maybe? But when being asked to write functional code, that means writing *declarative* code.

Comment: Right you are. I've written a little poem:
We don't need a stupid 'impl',
Just relax and keep it simple:)