# Why Do Methods In A For Expression Evaluate Per Loop

Tags: javascript

Given the code

```
var loops = 5;
var counter = 0;

function foo(counts){
    var baz = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<loops;i++){
        baz += i + counts;
    }
    return baz;
}

for(var i=0;i<foo(counter);i++){ //issue in this line
    console.log(i);
}
```

Every time that the for loop increments, it calls the foo function again.

Why is it doing this and is there a way to prevent this?

I understand that I can just store the return in a variable, but I'm still rather curious *why* this happens.

It doesn't happen in other languages like python.

The way I tested that it does this is by setting a breakpoint in the foo function.

Comment: `foo(counter)` calls foo until baz >= i as you ask it to. How is that a mystery? A for loop executes the test in between the ; ; each time

Comment: It's not a mystery that it calls it, but it calls it every time the loop runs. Instead of just once, and then using the returned value for each loop. Python does that. @mplungjan

Comment: I doubt that. Anyway do `for(var i=0, n=foo(counter); i<n; i++){   console.log(i); `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stop condition is evaluate each iteration.
If you want to evaluate only once do that:

```js
var loops = 5;
var counter = 0;

function foo(counts){
    var baz = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<loops;i++){
        baz += i + counts;
    }
    return baz;
}

for(var i=0,l=foo(counter);i<l;i++){ //issue in this line
    console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent python code would be

```
i = 0
while i < foo(counter):
    print(i)
    i++
```

That's just what a `for` loop does, the condition is evaluated before every iteration. If you want to call `foo` only once, you have to explicitly cache the result in a variable:

```
for (var i=0, n=foo(counter); i<n; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

The (more pythonic) alternative would be to use an [`range` generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30458295/1048572) (which is not available in the JS standard library though), where `foo` is called only once to create the iterator:

```
for (var i of range(0, foo(counter)) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: @mplungjan Yeah, `n` is a better variable name than `len` :-)

Comment: range is what i was using. Thank you. That makes sense, it was just hidden in the syntax. haha. The range generator is probably why it was only calling once.

Comment: @Bigbob556677 Indeed. Python is not that different from JavaScript in regard to how the evaluation works, it's just that the idiomatic range loops use different approaches.